# How to cache complex item into texture and release the memory for the actual complex item?

Tags: qt, caching, qml, textures, qtquick2

I've got a big number of items that are quite complex (memory-heavy), and in order to fit in limited RAM, I want to cache some of them into textures and not keep the actual complex item in memory. In particular, items for which I want to do that are all those (among my complex items) that do not currently need to animate (and this means most of them). For the purposes of this question I call this kind of items "inactive".

My plan was:

- When an item "foo" becomes inactive:

  - Create dynamically a `ShaderEffectSource` (with no associated `ShaderEffect`) with `live: false; source: foo`, in the same rectangle that was occupied by `foo`.
  - call `scheduleUpdate()` on the `ShaderEffectSource`
  - when the `ShaderEffectSource` becomes updated, call `destroy()` on `foo`

The problem with this plan is with the "when the `ShaderEffectSource` becomes updated" thing: there is no signal to notify me when that happens. I could use the fact (from [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shadereffectsource.html#scheduleUpdate-method)) that `scheduleUpdate()` schedules the update *for the next frame*. So I would maybe start a `Timer` that looks something like this:

```
Timer {
    interval: 1 // 1ms interval meaning "fire every frame"
    property int timesTriggered: 0
    repeat: true
    running: false

    onTriggered: {
        timesTriggered++;
        if(timesTriggered == 2) {
            complexItem.destroy();
            running = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The `== 2` check is to ensure that we've not only reached the next frame (which doesn't guaranteed that the scheduled update has happened already), but we've also reached the frame after that.

But that approach is a hack. **Any approach that is not a hack?**

Comment: Doesn't 60fps equal ~16.67ms per frame? So I think the `interval: 1` is quite hardcore.

Comment: There is a nice way to synchronize it with the actual frame rate, or even schedule a call on the next render loop.

Comment: @derM: I believe the QML Timer triggers are "synced" with the render loop so they never happen any faster than the scene refresh rate, even if you request a higher frequency. That's why I went ahead and chose "1ms".

Comment: Thats good to know!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to use `QQuickRenderControl`. I haven't had my time with it yet, but from the doc it sounds like it is exactly what you need:

> The QQuickRenderControl class provides a mechanism for **rendering the
>   Qt Quick scenegraph onto an offscreen render target in a fully
>   application-controlled manner**.
>
> QQuickWindow and QQuickView and their associated internal render loops
>   render the Qt Quick scene onto a native window. In some cases, for
>   example when integrating with 3rd party OpenGL renderers, it might be
>   beneficial to get the scene into a texture that can then be used in
>   arbitrary ways by the external rendering engine. **QQuickRenderControl
>   makes this possible in a hardware accelerated manner, unlike the
>   performance-wise limited alternative of using
>   QQuickWindow::grabWindow()**
>
> When using a QQuickRenderControl, the QQuickWindow does not have to be
>   shown or even created at all..
>
> Management of the context and framebuffer object is **up to the
>   application**...

There were some ways to achieve something similar prior to the introduction of `QQuickRenderControl`, but that adds a lot of convenience to the process. The texture don't have to traverse VRAM to RAM to VRAM, and you have full control of its lifetime and such, so you can implement a `QQuickItem` which basically just draws the texture using the efficient SG API.

Comment: I think that makes a nice escalation ladder: 1) Don't bother, 2) grabToImage (seems simpler), 3) QQuickRenderControl if nothing helps. It is something I should definitely dive into befor the world ends! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it with `grabToImage`

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: appWindow
    width: 1024
    height: 800
    visible: true
    Button {
        y: 410
        text: 'run ' + counter
        onClicked: foo()
    }
    property int counter: 0

    function foo() {
        counter++
        gc()
        var c = test.createObject(appWindow)
        c.grabToImage(function(result) {
            if (image.result) {               // <-- Delete what is possible
                image.result.image.destroy()
                image.result.destroy()
            } 
            image.result = result
        }, Qt.size(400, 400))
        c.destroy()
    }

    Image {
        id: image
        width: 400
        height: 400
        x: 100
        property var result
        source: result ? result.url : ''
        onSourceChanged: foo()
    }

    Component {
        id: test
        Grid {
            width: 400
            height: 400
            columns: 40
            rows: 40
            Repeater {
                model: 40 * 40
                delegate: Rectangle {
                    width: 10
                    height: 10
                    color: 'green'  // <--- don't always create a new color
                }
            }
            Component.onCompleted: console.log('Created')
            Component.onDestruction: console.log('Destroyed')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but consider this info from the grabToImage docs: "This function will render the item to an offscreen surface and copy that surface from the GPU's memory into the CPU's memory, which can be quite costly.". I'd like to avoid this cost if possible. OTOH when an item stops being "active", it's not urgent for me to snapshot it and delete it completely instantly, so `grabToImage` may work for me, especially as it seems it's async. I'll try it.

Comment: I need to admit that it might be a very bad solution, as I have not found a solution to clear the memory. The memory of the *complex object* is freed, but the result of `grabToImage` flees my puring gc() or anything else.m So with my given example, I manage to have 7 - 8 runs, until the app runs `out of memory`

Comment: Yeah, I changed the 200x200 grid to a 20x20 for faster testing, and when I repeatedly clicked the "run" button, memory usage went, in general, up. Though often it stayed the same or even went down, the general tendency was up. Even when I added `gc()` after the `c.destroy();`. Weird. Thanks for letting me know of this subtle trap.

Comment: Ok, it seems, the problem is, that within others, the function `Qt.rgba(...)` creates objects, that won't be deleted. I updated my code to reuse the color (just use the color `'green'` instead) and delete the result, when it is not needed any more. Now the memory consumption stays quite linear.