# Destroying an Item that was set as the sourceItem for a ShaderEffectSource hides the ShaderEffectSource as well

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

What I'm doing, in short:

- I have a `ShaderEffectSource` Item named `snapshotItem` with `live: false`
- Dynamically instantiating an Item called `dynamicItem`
- Setting `snapshotItem.sourceItem = dynamicItem`
- Calling `snapshotItem.scheduleUpdate()`
- At this point, I successfully see two copies of `dynamicItem` on screen
- On any key, I:

  - set `snapshotItem.sourceItem` to an empty, dummy Item, to make the next step less likely to cause problems
  - destroy `dynamicItem`

The problem is that when a key is pressed, both copies disappear from screen, when I want the `snapshotItem` one to remain.

*Note:* If you're interested in the motivation behind wanting to achieve this, see [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42698176).

My code:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    property int childWidth: 100
    property int childHeight: 100

    id: root
    property var dynamicItem

    Item {
        id: dummy
    }

    Component {
        id: dynamicItemComponent
        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        dynamicItem = dynamicItemComponent.createObject(row);
        dynamicItem.width = childWidth;
        dynamicItem.height = childHeight;
        snapshotItem.sourceItem = dynamicItem;
        snapshotItem.scheduleUpdate();
    }

    Item {
        focus: true
        Keys.onPressed: {
            snapshotItem.sourceItem = dummy;
            dynamicItem.destroy();
        }
    }

    Row {
        id: row
        spacing: 10
        ShaderEffectSource {
            id: snapshotItem
            live: false
            width: childWidth
            height: childHeight
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Following simple logic, disabling live and assigning a dummy object outta be more than enough to make it work the way you want, in fact, the first thing alone should have been enough. However, that is Qt, it doesn't always follow logic, actually very often it doesn't. Feel free to file a bug report, and possibly see this fixed, many years from now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a `dummyItem`. You can set the `sourceItem` to the `ShaderEffectSource` itself.

Maybe you should set `recursive` to `true`, but it also works without it.

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    property int childWidth: 100
    property int childHeight: 100

    id: root
    property var dynamicItem

    Component {
        id: dynamicItemComponent
        Rectangle {
            color: "red"
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        dynamicItem = dynamicItemComponent.createObject(row);
        dynamicItem.width = childWidth;
        dynamicItem.height = childHeight;
        snapshotItem.sourceItem = dynamicItem;
        snapshotItem.scheduleUpdate();
    }

    Item {
        focus: true
        Keys.onPressed: {
            snapshotItem.sourceItem = snapshotItem;
            dynamicItem.destroy();
        }
    }

    Row {
        id: row
        spacing: 10
        ShaderEffectSource {
            id: snapshotItem
            live: false
            // recursive: sourceItem === this
            width: childWidth
            height: childHeight
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I found that in [a slightly more involved scenario](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43101121), `recursive` does need to be set to `true`.