# Drawing QQuickItem's texture in a "draw-chain" through 2 QQuickFramebufferObjects fails

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2

First off, sorry for the long source code but I couldn't reduce it any further while still having the bug happen. Most of it is uninteresting boilerplate though, so you can mostly get away with just my human-readable summary below.

**Abbreviations used in this post:**

- QQFBO = QQuickFramebufferObject

**Observed result:** Two rotating squares, that's all.

**What's missing from the observed result:** A third, additional, non-rotating square, which is actually a static snapshot from the second one.

**What my code does, in short:**

- `class ClonerItem` is a QQFBO just fetches a texture from a QQuickItem and draws it to the screen.
- The `ClonerItemQml` is a Qml wrapper of ClonerItem that adds a `Timer` to it. Depending on the `ClonerItem.live` property, the timer either calls ClonerItem.update() constantly or not at all. **(basically the same the `live` property of Qt's `ShaderEffectSource`)**
- In `main.qml` I create a "producer-consumer-chain" of 3 items in a `RowLayout`.

  1. The first item is a rotating rectangle with `layer.enabled: true`.
  2. The second item is a `ClonerItemQml` (with `live: true`) that has the previous one as a texture source.
  3. The third item is a `ClonerItemQml` (called "`snapshotter`", with `live: false`) that has the the previous one as a texture source.
- "`snapshotter`" has its `update` method connected to 2 signals:

  1. A `firstRedraw` signal provided by item "2", which is called at the end of the first redraw of item "2"
  2. For testing, the `clicked` signal for "`snapshotter`", so you can see that the "`snapshotter`" does work correctly when you force it to update later during the program's execution.

**Any hints what I'm doing wrong?**

**Note:** When I remove the `Timer` and instead of it, uncomment the `if(m_live) update();` in `render`, it works fine.

**My code:**

*main.cpp*:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQuickFramebufferObject>
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QOpenGLFunctions>
#include <QOpenGLFramebufferObject>
#include <QQuickWindow>
// propertyhelper.h is from http://syncor.blogspot.bg/2014/11/qt-auto-property.html
#include "propertyhelper.h"
#include <QSGTextureProvider>

class ClonerItem : public QQuickFramebufferObject {
    Q_OBJECT

    AUTO_PROPERTY(QQuickItem*, sourceItem)
    AUTO_PROPERTY(bool, live)

public:
    Renderer* createRenderer() const;

signals:
    void firstRedraw();
};

class ClonerItemRenderer : public QObject, public QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer, protected QOpenGLFunctions {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ClonerItemRenderer() {
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();

        m_program.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, ":/shader.vert.glsl");
        m_program.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, ":/shader.frag.glsl");
        m_program.link();

        createGeometry();
    }

    void render() {
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        m_program.bind();
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        m_tex->bind();
        m_program.setUniformValue("uTex", 0);
        paintGeometry();
        glFlush();
        glFinish();
        m_window->resetOpenGLState();
        if(!m_haveRedrawnAtLeastOnce)
            emit firstRedraw();
        m_haveRedrawnAtLeastOnce = true;

        //if(m_live)
        //    update();
    }

    void paintGeometry() {
        m_program.enableAttributeArray("aPos");
        m_program.setAttributeArray("aPos", m_vertices.constData());
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, m_vertices.size());
    }

    void createGeometry() {
        m_vertices << QVector2D(-1, -1) << QVector2D(-1, +1) << QVector2D(+1, +1);
        m_vertices << QVector2D(-1, -1) << QVector2D(+1, -1) << QVector2D(+1, +1);
    }

    QOpenGLFramebufferObject* createFramebufferObject(const QSize &size) {
        QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat format;
        format.setAttachment(QOpenGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil);
        return new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(size, format);
    }

private:
    QVector<QVector2D> m_vertices;
    QOpenGLShaderProgram m_program;
    QQuickWindow* m_window;
    QSGTexture* m_tex;
    bool m_haveRedrawnAtLeastOnce = false;
    bool m_live;

protected:
    void synchronize(QQuickFramebufferObject* qqfbo) {
        ClonerItem* parentItem = (ClonerItem*)qqfbo;
        m_window = parentItem->window();
        m_live = parentItem->live();

        // fetch texture pointer
        QQuickItem* sourceItem = parentItem->sourceItem();
        QSGTextureProvider* sourceTexProvider = sourceItem->textureProvider();
        m_tex = sourceTexProvider->texture();
    }

signals:
    void firstRedraw();
};

QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer* ClonerItem::createRenderer() const {
    auto renderer = new ClonerItemRenderer();
    connect(renderer, &ClonerItemRenderer::firstRedraw, this, &ClonerItem::firstRedraw);
    return renderer;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<ClonerItem>("ClonerItem", 1, 0, "ClonerItem");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

*ClonerItem.qml*:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import ClonerItem 1.0

ClonerItem {
    id: root

    Timer {
        id: renderTimer
        running: root.live
        interval: 1000/60
        repeat: true

        onTriggered: {
            root.update();
        }
    }
}
```

*main.qml*:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import ClonerItem 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 200

    RowLayout {
        id: rowLayout
        anchors.fill: parent
        Item {
            id: original
            layer.enabled: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            RotatingSquare { }
        }
        ClonerItemQml {
            id: liveClone
            layer.enabled: true
            sourceItem: original
            live: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            onFirstRedraw: {
                snapshotter.update();
            }
        }
        ClonerItemQml {
            id: snapshotter
            sourceItem: liveClone
            live: false
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    snapshotter.update();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*RotatingSquare.qml*:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    color: "red"
    border.color: "black"
    width: parent.width / 2
    height: parent.height / 2
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    NumberAnimation on rotation {
        running: true
        loops: Animation.Infinite
        duration: 1000
        from: 0
        to: 360
    }
}
```

*shader.frag.glsl*:

```
varying highp vec2 vTexCoord;
uniform sampler2D uTex;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTex, vTexCoord);
}
```

*shader.vert.glsl*

```
attribute highp vec2 aPos;
varying highp vec2 vTexCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 0.0, 1.0);
    // aPos's components are in [-1, 1], transform them to the range [0, 1] for use as texcoords.
    vTexCoord = aPos * .5 + vec2(.5);
}
```

If you're wondering why I'm doing such an elaborate/weird setup, I can elucidate: in my real app the second item in the "chain" is not a simple "cloner" but actually uses its source texture(s) for some more-complex rendering (which is also memory-hungry). And the third item in the "chain" is necessary to snapshot the result of the second one, so the second one can be destroyed when not animated, freeing up memory.

The reason I implement my own `ClonerItem` component, which does basically the same as Qt's `ShaderEffectSource`, is [this Qt bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42722471).