# Recursion trick in ShaderEffectSource fails when I destroy the source object in onStateChanged

Tags: qt, caching, recursion, qml, qtquick2

I want a `ShaderEffectSource` called `snapshotter` that updates on every change of a source item, but when the source item is destroyed, I want `snapshotter` to retain the last state of the source item.

In my code I use [a workaround for a Qt deficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43067294) - setting `snapshotter.sourceItem = snapshotter` when the previous source item gets destroyed. **This works fine** when I destroy the old source item e.g. on key press. But when I do it in an `onStateChanged` handler, I get this error:

> ShaderEffectSource: 'recursive' must be set to true when rendering recursively.

But I don't want to set `recursive: true`, because then `snapshotter` would start repainting as fast as possible, wasting a lot of processing power.

Any idea why that problem happens **considering it works fine when using key press**, and/or a workaround?

I realize I'm asking why a *hacky solution* fails in some cases, but since it works in some cases, I'd like to use the solution anyway as it's very useful.

**My code:** (main.qml)

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Loader {
        active: true
        id: loader
        sourceComponent:
            Rectangle {
                color: "red"
                border.color: "white"
                width: 100
                height: 100
                parent: row

                states: [
                    State {
                        // the condition is always true, in this example code
                        name: "theOnlyState"; when: width === 100
                    }
                ]
                onStateChanged: {
                    if(state === "theOnlyState") {
                        loader.active = false;
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    Row {
        id: row
        ShaderEffectSource {
            id: snapshotItem
            sourceItem: {
                if(loader.status === Loader.Ready) {
                    return loader.item;
                } else {
                    return snapshotItem;
                }
            }
            live: loader.status === Loader.Ready
            width: 100
            height: 100
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** I just had an idea: maybe setting `recursive: true` will not create the problem I mentioned, considering I'd only set it when `live == false`. Maybe Qt is smart enough not constantly redraw in that case. But I'm not sure how to check if that's true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found an 99%-authorative answer.

The worry about `recursive: true` that I expressed in the question was provoked by my vague memory of reading something like that in the Qt docs.

I now went ahead and looked up the [relevant passage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shadereffectsource.html#recursive-prop) again, and here's what it says:

> Setting both this property and `live` to true will cause the scene graph to render continuously. Since the `ShaderEffectSource` depends on itself, updating it means that it immediately becomes dirty again.

Note how they say that for the bad scenario to occur, `live` has to be `true`.

So the solution is to simply use `recursive: true`, which makes the solution much less hacky.

**Note:** I'm not gonna mark this answer accepted, because I'd like people to still go over it now and then and maybe, just maybe, prove me wrong (e.g. show that I'm misinterpreting the text).

---

**More evidence in favor of the above conclusion:**

I set the env var `QSG_VISUALIZE` to `changes` and ran this trivival test app:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ShaderEffectSource {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        id: shaderEffectSource
        live: false
        sourceItem: shaderEffectSource
        recursive: true
    }
}
```

It showed an unchanging colored square. But when I changed `live` to `true` in this code, it started flickering in random colors.

Answer (score 0):

As you found out yourself, when you have `live = false` and `recursive = true` it won't be redrawn all the time.

I think the problem of yours might arise due to the [magic](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-statesanimations-states.html#state-fast-forwarding), QML uses for its state machine, going back and forth and so on...

As far as I understand your problem, you want to create an object, take a snapshot, and delete it right after that again.
This is easier achieved by using methods and signals than by some declarative state changes and so on.

Specifically you might be looking for [`scheduleUpdate()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shadereffectsource.html#scheduleUpdate-method) to render the next frame, without the need of setting `live = true`. The next thing you will be interested in is the signal: `scheduledUpdateCompleted` to delete your object again.

Something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
ApplicationWindow {
    width: 1024
    height: 800
    visible: true

    Button {
        text: 'Next'
        onClicked: {
            ses.sourceItem = prototype.createObject(ses)
        }
    }

    ShaderEffectSource {
        id: ses
        y: 100
        width: 50
        height: 50
        live: false
        onSourceItemChanged: if (sourceItem !== this) scheduleUpdate()
        onScheduledUpdateCompleted: {
            sourceItem.destroy()
            sourceItem = this
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: prototype
        Rectangle {
            width: 50
            height: 50
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(-1), Math.random(0), Math.random(1))
            visible: false
            Component.onCompleted: console.log('Created new Rectangle with color', color)
            Component.onDestruction: console.log('Destroy Rectangle with color', color)
        }
    }
}
```

**Remember:** The `sourceItem` does not have to be visible to be rendered into an `ShaderEffectSource`. If it is not necessary for other reasons, I would keep it invisible, so it is not rendered twice.

Comment: Thanks. Where did you learn about the `scheduledUpdateCompleted` signal? It doesn't seem to be documented. Maybe it's not intended for general/outside use?

Comment: I learned about it from the auto complete of the QtCreator ;-) I'll file a bugreport later, to see if I migth get it documented. If so, we can be sure, it is intended for general use.