# Snapshot via ShaderEffectSource is sometimes jaggy

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2

My component's code was this:

```
import QtQuick 2.5

Item {
    id: root

    width: 315
    height: 315

    property bool active

    Image {
        id: srcImage
        width: root.width
        height: root.height

        source: "/test.png"

        y: root.active ? 0 : 300
    }

    ShaderEffectSource {
        id: snapshotter
        sourceItem: {
            if(root.active) {
                return srcImage;
            } else {
                // Work around a bug that causes the snapshotter to lose its
                // contents. (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/43067294 )
                return snapshotter;
            }
        }
        width: root.width
        height: root.height
        live: root.active
        recursive: sourceItem == snapshotter
        textureSize: Qt.size(root.width, root.height)
        y: live ? 300 : 0
    }
}
```

And I was getting results like this (side by side broken and unbroken):

[image: screenshot]

I figured out the cause and I'll post it directly as an answer.

Comment: Shader output doesn't appear to support antialiasing in qml: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40329703/force-the-scenegraph-to-antialias-the-output-of-shadereffect It may even be a bug.

Comment: @dtech: The question you link is about a different problem - aliasing of edge pixels of the OpenGL geometry. In my case the problem is visible throughout the entire texture.

Answer (score 1):

I had to ensure that the absolute coordinates (window-relative) of the component are integers. That fixed it.